# What is the pattern for entities and Equatable?

Tags: swift

Suppose I have this base class:

```swift
class Entity: Equatable {

  init() {
  }

  var localId: Int32?
  var id: Int32?
}

func == (lhs: Entity, rhs: Entity) -> Bool {
  return object_getClassName(lhs) == object_getClassName(rhs) &&
    lhs.localId != nil &&
    rhs.localId != nil &&
    lhs.localId == rhs.localId
}
```

and a number of entity implementations along the lines of this:

```swift
class Message: Entity {

  init(senderId: Int32, body: String, sentDateTime: NSDate) {
    self.senderId = senderId
    self.body = body
    self.sentDateTime = sentDateTime
    super.init()
  }

  var senderId: Int32
  var body: String
  var sentDateTime: NSDate
}
```

Am I taking the right approach with the `Equatable` implementation? The reason I compare the class names is that uniqueness of `localId` is scoped to each entity type. Should I instead implement `Equatable` for each entity class? Is there an established pattern in Swift for this kind of thing?

Answer (score 0):

The first big question is whether `localId` and `id` really have to be optional. And if this is all that `Entity` does, it seems much more natural as a protocol rather than a superclass. And it's not clear why `senderId` etc. are `var` rather than `let`. But these are separate issues from the main question.

To the equality check.

I don't believe you need all the `!= nil` checks here. This should be ok (at least in my tests):

```
func == (lhs: Entity, rhs: Entity) -> Bool {
  return object_getClassName(lhs) == object_getClassName(rhs) &&
    lhs.localId == rhs.localId
}
```

But I don't see any problem with the basic idea here.

(You'd think you could use `lhs.dynamictype == rhs.dynamicType`, but surprisingly (to me) that doesn't compile currently.)

Comment: The idea is that `localId` is populated when the entity is inserted into the local database and `id` is populated when the entity is synchronized to or downloaded from the remote database. There are cases in which either or both of them can be `nil`. I didn't know about `dynamicType` and it seems odd that `==` doesn't work. It seems strange that there is not a simple way to check that two objects are of the same type without extending `NSObject`.