# swift - Can I compare Any.Type?

Tags: ios, swift

I defined two types as follow: I want to define a function 'matches' that compares two KeyTypePairs and returns true or false depends on matching on key and type.

```
protocol KeyTypePair: Hashable {
    typealias val

    var key: String { get }
    var type: Any.Type { get }
}

public struct KeyTypePairOf<T>: KeyTypePair {
    typealias val = T

    let _key: String
    let _type: Any.Type

    public var key: String {
        get {
            return _key
        }
    }

    public var type: Any.Type {
        get {
            return _type
        }
    }

    public var hashValue: Int {
        get {
            return _key.hashValue
        }
    }

    public init(key: String) {
        self._key = key
        self._type = T.self
    }

    init<T: KeyTypePair>(property: T) {
        self._key = pair.key
        self._type = pair.type
    }

    func matches<T: KeyTypePair>(pair:T) -> Bool {
        let x = self._type == pair.type // invalid, how do I check equal types?
        return self._key == pair.key && x
    }

}
```

How do I compare the 'types' of the struct? Been a headache. Should I use AnyObject instead?

Answer (score 5):

I tested this in a Swift 4 playground

```
struct Foo {}
struct Bar {}

let fooType: Any.Type = Foo.self
let barType: Any.Type = Bar.self

fooType == Foo.self  // true
fooType is Foo.Type  // true
fooType == barType   // false
```

Answer (score 2):

The tool you want is `object_getClassName` (which returns a `String`). Right now, you can't directly compare types. This feels like just a missing compiler feature rather than anything deep about swift. You'd think you could compare `x.dynamicType == y.dynamicType`, but that doesn't currently work. See also [What is the pattern for entities and Equatable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25949975/what-is-the-pattern-for-entities-and-equatable/25965732#25965732)

Comment: You can only use `object_getClassName` for objects. If they were both objects, you can use `x.dynamicType as AnyObject === y.dynamicType as AnyObject`